# Why such an error for an Image caption task using CNN and LSTM

Tags: image, deep-learning, lstm, vgg-net

Generating a description for an image caption using VGG16 and LSTM, ran the code but its givig an error.

````
# train the model, run epochs manually and save after each epoch
epochs = 20
steps = len(train_descriptions)
for i in range(epochs):
    # create the data generator
    generator = data_generator(train_descriptions, train_features, tokenizer, max_length)
    # fit for one epoch
    #Model.fit(generator, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=steps, verbose=1)
    model.fit(generator, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=steps, verbose=1)
    # save model
    model.save('model_' + str(i) + '.h5')```

Here is the outcome
````

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_12120\3782113586.py in 
10         # fit for one epoch
11         #Model.fit(generator, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=steps, verbose=1)
---> 12         model.fit(generator, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=steps, verbose=1)
13         # save model
14         model.save('model_' + str(i) + '.h5')

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
71         finally:
72             del filtered_tb

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
50   try:
51     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
53                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
54   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'model_2/dense/Relu' defined at (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 17, in 
app.launch_new_instance()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
app.start()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 712, in start
self.io_loop.start()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 199, in start
self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 601, in run_forever
self._run_once()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1905, in _run_once
handle._run()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 510, in dispatch_queue
await self.process_one()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 499, in process_one
await dispatch(*args)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 406, in dispatch_shell
await result
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 730, in execute_request
reply_content = await reply_content
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 390, in do_execute
res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 528, in run_cell
return super().run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2914, in run_cell
result = self._run_cell(
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2960, in _run_cell
return runner(coro)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\async_helpers.py", line 78, in *pseudo_sync_runner
coro.send(None)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3185, in run_cell_async
has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3377, in run_ast_nodes
if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async*=asy)):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3457, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "C:\Users\Adejimi AA\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_12120\3782113586.py", line 12, in 
model.fit(generator, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=steps, verbose=1)
File "C:\Users\Adejimi AA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Adejimi AA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1685, in fit
tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
File "C:\Users\Adejimi AA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1284, in train_function
return step_function(self, iterator)
File "C:\Users\Adejimi AA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1268, in step_function
outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "C:\Users\Adejimi AA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1249, in run_step
outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "C:\Users\Adejimi AA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1050, in train_step
y_pred = self(x, training=True)
File "C:\Users\Adejimi AA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Adejimi AA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 558, in **call**
return super().**call**(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Adejimi AA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Adejimi AA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1145, in **call**
outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Adejimi AA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Adejimi AA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 512, in call
return self._run_internal_graph(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
File "C:\Users\Adejimi AA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 669, in _run_internal_graph
outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Adejimi AA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Adejimi AA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1145, in **call**
outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Adejimi AA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Adejimi AA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\layers\core\dense.py", line 255, in call
outputs = self.activation(outputs)
File "C:\Users\Adejimi AA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\activations.py", line 317, in relu
return backend.relu(
File "C:\Users\Adejimi AA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line 5396, in relu
x = tf.nn.relu(x)
Node: 'model_2/dense/Relu'
Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [53,1000], In[1]: [4096,256]
[[{{node model_2/dense/Relu}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1035897]```